# How can I send a continuous stream of timeupdate events efficiently to socket server?

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io, system, pusher

I have an Angular P2P video sharing app and I'm trying to keep users watching a video, in sync.

I need to add the functionality for when a user seeks to a different time in the video, it should also seek for other users.

I have the following code in my component constructor:

```
this.player.on('timeupdate', () => {


// Send a time update to socket
console.log(this.player.currentTime());
this.comm.timeUpdate(this.player.currentTime());


});
```

This approach is inefficient because the timeupdate is occurring every millisecond or even nanosecond and my socket push server has a 200k daily message/event limit and these events are adding up very quickly.

How do I go about sending these timeupdate events without exhausting my socket server limit?

Update 1:

-I haven't deployed the app yet but I'm expecting around 50 concurrent users watching a video. I need to keep the videos synced in real-time.

-I'm currently using the Pusher socket solution (free-tier)

- Here is the code for my comm service:

  timeUpdate( currTime ){
  this.channel.trigger('client-time' , {time: currTime});
  }

Comment: How many users do you have listening for these events? Sometimes it just isn't realistic to be able to reduce the number of events being generated and maintain the same functionality.
What socket solution are you currently using? Can you share the code for `this.comm.timeUpdate():`?

Comment: I updated the question with the details.

Comment: The best approach in this scenario would be to rate limit your client events. Is it required to actually send the time update every millisecond? Would a user realise if you started to send these events once per second instead? 
Alternatively, you could consider only sending an event when a significant change takes place. For example, you could use Pusher to send play/pause events, ensuring the playback starts at the same time, and for when a user seeks to a new time. Normal playback is in sync already, as playback started at the same time, so this should be sufficient.